# Asp.net MVC Html.TextboxFor title and validation message conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I have a Asp.net MVC application(using Razor View) in which i am using Html.Textboxfor for textbox. Below is the code :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Textbox1, Model.Attributes)
```

The attributes i am adding for these are

```
Model.Attributes = new Dictionary<string,object>);                               
Model.Attributes .Add("size", "3");
Model.Attributes .Add("min", 0);
Model.Attributes .Add("max", 100);                               
Model.Attributes .Add("title", "Value");
```

So when i click on submit i am validating the Textbox and it shows the default title as error message when data outside the specified range is entered. Any way to prevent this from happening and add a custom error message different from title?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use data annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not sure what u try to do but i think u need just use data anotation

```
 [StringLength(100,  MinimumLength=1, ErrorMessage = "error message here")]
 public string title { get; set; }
```